# Reserve hotel from Barcelona airport?

Tags: barcelona, bcn

I am travelling from NYC to Barcelona, and returning back. If I miss my return flight to NYC, and my next flight is a one day later, how can I reserver hotel from Barcelona airport?

I do not speak spanish, or have a laptop to reserve online.

Is there some facility to book hotel from tourist information desk etc, from the Barcelona Airport?

Barcelona airport and Paris airports are two different airports, with probably different ways to function. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reserve hotel from Paris airport](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62245/reserve-hotel-from-paris-airport) Please do not ask the same question for every airport .

Comment: Why do you miss so many long-haul flights?

Comment: Sounds like you will have been staying in Barcelona already? If so, keep a note of the phone number of the place you've been staying at. Give them a ring, explain you've missed your flight and want to come back. They'll either book you back in if they can, or since you're a past guest, they'll likely help find you something else if they're full

Comment: Disagree with the dupe vote, this is about Barcelona not Paris, although the answers are likely to be similar

Comment: The "Hotel Tonight" app is very useful in this kind of situation

Comment: Duplicate. The answer is going to be the same for every major airport in every part of the world, with only a tiny number of exceptions.

Comment: I did this a couple of years ago in BCN, there was a booth with a list of hotels ( and if memory serves me well, there was a phone); I called a few of them and got a reservation.

Comment: Technically not a duplicate since only questions can be, as opposed to answers. I'm torn. Skipping this review.

Answer (score 2):

Will you have a smartphone? Many hotel booking sites (Hipmunk, Kayak, booking.com, Expedia, hotwire, etc...) have mobile apps and/or websites that work on mobile phones. You can also find hotels online and call them to make a reservation. Most hotels in Barcelona should have someone who speaks English to assist you.

Or, if you were just staying in Barcelona, call whatever hotel you just checked out of and see if they have room for you to return for another night.

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of hotels close to the airport on the [airport's official site](http://www.aena.es/csee/Satellite/Aeropuerto-Barcelona/en/Page/1085473344970/). 
You can try to call them, otherwise they most probably will be able to help you at any [information point](http://www.aena.es/csee/Satellite/Aeropuerto-Barcelona/en/Page/1045569607403//Information-points-in-the-airport.html#Information%20points%20in%20the%20airport). Also [tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/HotelsNear-g187497-qBCN-Barcelona_Catalonia.html) shows a list of hotels close to the airport.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are all things you should do first, but if all else fails, and you have no access to a phone or a computer, almost all international airports have a 'travellers aid' or similarly named desk, who are there to handle situations like this. Talk to them. They will speak English and will almost certainly book a hotel for you.