# Reserve hotel from Paris airport

Tags: france, accommodation, cdg

I am travelling from NYC to Paris, and returning back. If I miss my return flight to NYC, and my next flight is a one day later, how can I reserver hotel from CDG airport?

I do not speak French nor have a laptop to reserve online.

Is there some facility to book hotel from tourist information desk etc, from the CDG Airport?

Comment: Will you have a smartphone? Many hotel booking sites (Hipmunk, Kayak, booking.com, Expedia, hotwire, etc...) have mobile apps and/or websites that work on mobile phones. You can also find hotels and call them to make a reservation. Or, if you were just staying in Paris, call whatever hotel you just checked out of and see if they have room for you to return.

Comment: I'll add that major hotels, and likely a good number of medium-sized ones, should be able to get an English speaker on the phone to help you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Sheraton hotel built into the Airport at Paris CDG](https://www.starwoodhotels.com/sheraton/property/overview/index.html?propertyID=125&language=en_US). It's in Terminal 2, by the VAL shuttle train between the terminals, and very close to the railway station.

As a non-French speaker with no laptop, this will be by far your easiest and least stress option. (Not the cheapest mind)

So, your best option is just to head there - use the free shuttle train if you're not in Terminal 2, then follow the signs. Walk up to reception and ask for a room. They're a US chain, so all the staff will speak English. If they have a room, great! Pay up, get the key, and you're set. If they're fully booked, then the reception staff (when not serving other guests) should be able to help you find another nearby hotel with space.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a wifi enabled phone, you can use the [free wifi](http://www.aeroportsdeparis.fr/en/passengers/services/wifi-internet-multimedia/wifi) provided at the airport to find yourself another place to stay. Kayak, Booking, Expedia and tons of other sites have apps for that. They also have "multimedia stations" where you can use a computer to do just that (though that option only gives you 15 free minutes after which you'd have to pay)

If not, there are plenty of [hotels](https://www.booking.com/airport/fr/cdg.html) in the airport or within walking distance. You could keep a list of some of these phone numbers just in case, and call any of them from the airport (there are pay phones). It's doubtful that an airport hotel in a capital wouldn't have any English speaking staff to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Roissy is a big airport with plenty of hotels around it. Depending on your budget and style, you can select the best one for you :

- [Sheraton](http://www.starwoodhotels.com/sheraton/property/overview/index.html?propertyID=125&language=fr_FR) : connected to the airport terminal
- [Hyatt Regency](http://paris.charlesdegaulle.hyatt.com/fr/hotel/home.html) : has a shuttle to go to and from the airport from the hotel, it has an indoor pool
- [Hilton](http://www.hiltonhotels.com/fr_FR/france/hilton-paris-charles-de-gaulle-airport/) : also has a shuttle and an indoor pool

There are plenty of other hotels as well :)

Then, you have [a page on the airport website](http://www.aeroportsdeparis.fr/en/passengers/services/practical-services/hotels/charles-de-gaulle) that describes where to go to find the shuttles.

I am pretty sure that you can find desks in the airport that will assist you in finding an hotel if you can't make an online booking. I believe there are phones to call them directly from the airport as well.

Last but not least, a lot of hotels are offering refundable bookings. So you can make a booking now and then just cancel it if you realize that you won't need it. But don't worry, I am 90% sure that you'll find an hotel in Roissy on last minute. And if you don't, just get outside of Roissy, there are nice hotels in Chantilly for instance.

Comment: Note that 2pm / 4pm / 6pm cancellations are getting a lot rarer these days. Increasingly you need to cancel the day before to avoid a penalty even on most flexible rates, which won't work for the OP, so they'll need to take great care when booking to ensure they get free same-day cancellation if doing that!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are all things you should do first, but if all else fails, and you have no access to a phone or a computer, almost all airports have a 'travellers aid' or similarly named desk, who are there to handle situations like this. Talk to them. They will speak English and will almost certainly book a hotel for you.